# Select All Checkbox and CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a form that contains two elements: a `CheckedListBox` and a `CheckBox`. The `CheckBox`, which is called `SelectAllCheckBox`, is used to check/uncheck all items in the `CheckedListBox`. I achieve this via a `CheckedChanged` event handler associated with the `SelectAllCheckBox`, so that when it is checked, all items in the `CheckedListBox` are checked, and vice versa. This works fine.

I also have code that unchecks the `SelectAllCheckBox` when the user unchecks one of the CheckBoxes in the `CheckedListBox`. For example, if the user checks the `SelectAllCheckBox`, and then unchecks one of the items, the Select All `CheckBox` should be unchecked. This is achieved via the `CheckedListBox.ItemChecked` event handler. This also works fine.

My problem is that when the `SelectAllCheckBox` is programatically unchecked (as in the above scenario), its event handler causes all items in the `CheckedListBox` to become unchecked.

I'm sure others have run into my issue; is there an elegant workaround?

Comment: Could please post some of your code for us to work with?

Comment: code will be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to utilize the fact that when you programmatically check/uncheck, it does not give focus to the checkbox. So you can use the `Focused` property as a flag.

```
private void SelectAllCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!((CheckBox)sender).Focused) 
       return;
    //your code to uncheck/check all CheckedListBox here
}
```

No need to create another separate bool flag (unless if you are manually changing the focus state somewhere).

Comment: Clever. This is what I was looking for - a way to distinguish between programmatic and user checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some flag:

```
 bool suppressCheckedChanged;
 private void SelectAllCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(suppressCheckedChanged) return;
    //your code here
    //....
 }
 //Then whenever you want to programmatically change the Checked of your SelectAllCheckBox
 //you can do something like this
 suppressCheckedChanged = true;
 SelectAllCheckBox.Checked = false;
 suppressCheckedChanged = false;
```

Another approach is you can try another kind of event such as `Click` and `DoubleClick` (must use both):

```
private void SelectAllCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   DoStuff();
}
private void SelectAllCheckBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
   DoStuff();
}
private void DoStuff(){
   //your code here;
   if(SelectAllCheckBox.Checked){
      //....
   }
   else {
     //....
   }
}
```